# Authenticate with Google OAuth2 in unit test in Python Django

Tags: python, django, unit-testing, oauth-2.0, google-oauth

I'm working on a Django project that uses Google OAuth2 to authenticate users. It's the first time I work with OAuth2 authentication, so my knowledge of Google OAuth2 is from the resources I found in the web today.

In writing unit tests for the application I need to authenticate in it, and I don't know how to do it inside a `unittest.TestCase` test suit.

How to authenticate to the application using Google OAuth2 in unit tests suits?

Answer (score 0):

U need use https://docs.python.org/3/library/unittest.mock.html ,
I have used such construction:

```
with mock.patch('google.oauth2.id_token.verify_oauth2_token') as 
mock_verify_oauth2_token:
    mock_verify_oauth2_token.return_value = MOCK_RETURN_VALUE_DATA
```

where:

```
MOCK_RETURN_VALUE_DATA=some_data
```

in my case...